# Binding NSTextField to NSString

Tags: objective-c, binding, xcode4.3, cocoa-bindings, nstextfield

I have a very simple question I hope someone can answer as I start understanding bindings. I want to programmatically change my NSString value and have the NSTextField update to that value thru bindings. I have a NSTextField and NSLabel. To represent the value of the myString properly changing I have a NSButton.

- I have NSTextField's Value bound to myString property of App Delegate with Continuously Update Value checked.
- I have NSLabel's Value bound to myString Property of App Delegate.
- I have NSButton outlet hooked to setDefault method.

When I type in NSTextField the NSLabel updates as expected but when I click the button the myString property is updated but not in the NSTextField.

What do I need to do to get the NSTextField update to the myString property????

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate>
{
   NSString *myString;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property NSString *myString;

- (IBAction)setDefault:(id)sender;
@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize myString;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
   myString = @"This is a string";
}

- (IBAction)setDefault:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"%@", myString);
   myString = @"This is a string";
   NSLog(@"%@", myString);
}
@end
```

Comment: You should somewhen mark the question as answered.

Comment: How do I mark it as answered???

Comment: You should see an [arrow next to each answer](http://postimage.org/image/636tqai21/). You can only mark one answer as the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't be

```
myString = @"This is a string";
```

but this:

```
self.myString = @"This is a string";
```

both in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` and in `-setDefault:`. Don't forget to specify self in your NSLog statements as well. You'd probably like to specify a different string in `-setDefault:` so that you can actually see that a change is taking place.

One other thing: You're effectively saying that you want to assign to myString, but that's not appropriate for an object. Instead of:

```
@property NSString *myString;
```

you should instead use

```
@property (copy) NSString *myString;
```

or at least

```
@property (retain) NSString *myString;
```

The former is preferred because passing a `NSMutableString` instance effectively copies it as a `NSString`, while passing a `NSString` instance simply retains it.

Good luck to you in your endeavors.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you prefix your member variables. This way you can **distinguish between setting the member directly or using the setter**. In your example I would do the following.

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate>
{
   NSString *m_myString;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property NSString *myString;

- (IBAction)setDefault:(id)sender;
@end
```

...

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize myString = m_myString;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
   self.myString = @"This is a string";
}

- (IBAction)setDefault:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"%@", m_myString);
   self.myString = @"This is a string";
   NSLog(@"%@", m_myString);
}
@end
```

Notice, that I changed the `@synthesize` to assign the member variable.

To clarify:

```
self.myString = @"This is a string";
```

.. is an alternative syntax for ...

```
[self setMyString:@"This is a string"];
```

You can also set the member directly ...

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"myString"];
m_myString = @"This is a string";
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"myString"];
```

But then you need to "inform" observers of the binding as illustrated above.